# SQL query to return rows with one distinct field and use CASE to create new evaluation column

Tags: sql, case, distinct

I want to write an SQL query to return rows with one distinct field and use CASE to create new evaluation column. Any help is appreciated. Deets below:

table

| id | status | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| string | string | bigint |
| -------- | -------- | ---------- |

pseudo query:

return (distinct *id*), *time_created*, *NEW_COL*
where *category* is 123123
and where *new_col* //create new col with these values
(
if status = 'good' then 'GOOD'
if status = 'bad' then 'BAD'
)
FROM table

result:

| id | time_created | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jun-1 | BAD |
| 2 | Jul-21 | GOOD |
| 3 | Jun-12 | GOOD |
| 4 | Aug-1 | GOOD |

--- I keep getting a lint error right on my CASE keyword:
"expecting " '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||',""

one of queries I tried:
SELECT
ID, time_created
CASE
WHEN status = 'good' THEN 'GOOD'
WHEN status = 'bad' THEN 'BAD'
END
as STATUS_new
FROM TBL
WHERE CATEGORY = '871654671'
ORDER BY time_created

Comment: Please edit your question and post your actual query, not the pseudo query

Comment: use https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to create an example with your schema and data. then it's easier to understand your situation and faster to help you.

Comment: thanks -> here it is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7293b5/1 @SergejTihonov

Comment: missing comma(,) after time_created and before CASE

Answer (score 0):

You just have a small syntax error (and bad column name in your sql fiddle). You just need a comma after the time created column.

```
SELECT
        ID, time as time_created,
        CASE 
          WHEN status = 'good' THEN 'GOOD' 
          WHEN status = 'bad' THEN 'BAD'
         END
         as STATUS_new
 FROM TBL
 WHERE CATEGORY = '871654671'
 ORDER BY time_created
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working query:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7293b5/11

```
 SELECT
       ID, TIME, 'STATUS_new' =
        CASE STATUS
          WHEN 'good' THEN 'GOOD' 
          WHEN 'bad' THEN 'BAD'
         END
 FROM TBL
 WHERE CATEGORY = '871654671'
 ORDER BY TIME
```

1. you must put the new name of the column before the `CASE`
2. the column you are defining the `CASE` must be defined directly behind the case and all the `WHEN` conditions are directly related to it.
3. in your fiddle you used the wrong column name of your `TIME` column